# Cómo gurdar en local storage el theme que el usuario seleccione?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando guardar el tema que los usuarios eligan desde un moda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El CODIGO ES ESTE: `
(todo sobre el cambio de color esta funcionando, solo hace falta que lo guarde en local storage).
Para plantearlo de una mejor manera el  id del theme abre un modal como el de la imagen, el html que les he mostrado son las diferentes opciones que muestra el modal. Ahora bien. El cambio de todo lo hace a la perfección.

Es decir que es lo unico que falta, he visto videos de localstorage pero no lo he conseguido.

```js
// THEME
const theme = document.querySelector('#theme');
const themeModal = document.querySelector('.customize-theme');
const fontSizes = document.querySelectorAll('.choose-size span');
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
const colorPalette = document.querySelectorAll('.choose-color span');
const Bg1 = document.querySelector('.bg-1');
const Bg2 = document.querySelector('.bg-2');
const Bg3 = document.querySelector('.bg-3');

// THEME/DISPLAY CUSTOMIZATION

// opens modal
const openThemeModal = () => {
    themeModal.style.display = 'grid';
}

// close modal
themeModal.addEventListener('click', closeThemeModal);

theme.addEventListener('click', openThemeModal);


// ======================== FONTS =========================

// remove active class from spans or font size selectors
const removeSizeSelector = () => {
    fontSizes.forEach(size => {
        size.classList.remove('active');
    })
}

fontSizes.forEach(size => {
    size.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeSizeSelector();
        let fontSize;
        size.classList.toggle('active');

        if(size.classList.contains('font-size-1')){
            fontSize = '10px';
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-left', '5.4rem');
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-right', '5.4rem');
        } else if(size.classList.contains('font-size-2')){
            fontSize = '13px';
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-left', '5.4rem');
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-right', '-7rem');
        } else if(size.classList.contains('font-size-3')){
            fontSize = '16px';
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-left', '-2rem');
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-right', '-17rem');
        } else if(size.classList.contains('font-size-4')){
            fontSize = '19px';
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-left', '-5rem');
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-right', '-25rem');
        } else if(size.classList.contains('font-size-5')){
            fontSize = '22px';
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-left', '-12rem');
            root.style.setProperty('----sticky-top-right', '-35rem');
        }

        // change font size of the root html element
    document.querySelector('html').style.fontSize = fontSize;
    })
    
})



// remove active class from colors
const changeActiveColorClass = () => {
    colorPalette.forEach(colorPicker => {
        colorPicker.classList.remove('active');
    })
}

// change primary colors
colorPalette.forEach(color => {
    color.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let primary;
        // remove active class from colors
        changeActiveColorClass();

        if(color.classList.contains('color-1')){
            primaryHue = 252;
        } else if(color.classList.contains('color-2')){
            primaryHue = 52;
        } else if(color.classList.contains('color-3')){
            primaryHue = 352;
        } else if(color.classList.contains('color-4')){
            primaryHue = 152;
        } else if(color.classList.contains('color-5')){
            primaryHue = 202;
        }
        color.classList.add('active');

        root.style.setProperty('--primary-color-hue', primaryHue);
    })
})


/ theme BACKGROUND values
let lightColorLightness;
let whiteColorLightness;
let darkColorLightness;

// changes background color
const changeBG = () => {
    root.style.setProperty('--light-color-lightness', lightColorLightness);
    root.style.setProperty('--white-color-lightness', whiteColorLightness);
    root.style.setProperty('--dark-color-lightness', darkColorLightness);
}


// change background colors
Bg1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // add active class
    Bg1.classList.add('active');
    // remove active class from the others
    Bg2.classList.remove('active');
    Bg3.classList.remove('active');
    // remove customized changes from local storage
    window.location.reload();
});

Bg2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    darkColorLightness = '95%';
    whiteColorLightness = '20%';
    lightColorLightness = '15%';
    
    // add active class
    Bg2.classList.add('active');
    // remove active class from the others
    Bg1.classList.remove('active');
    Bg3.classList.remove('active');
    changeBG();
});

Bg3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    darkColorLightness = '95%';
    whiteColorLightness = '10%';
    lightColorLightness = '0%';

    // add active class
    Bg3.classList.add('active');
    // remove active class from others
    Bg1.classList.remove('active');
    Bg2.classList.remove('active');
    changeBG();
})
```

```html
 <!--================================================ THEME CUSTOMIZATION =============================================-->
 
<a class="menu-item" id="theme"> <span><i class="uil uil-palette"></i></span><h3>Theme</h3></a>

 <div class="customize-theme">
    <div class="card">
        <h2>Customize your view</h2>
        <p class="text-muted">Manage your font size, color, and background.</p>

        <!------------ FONT SIZES ------------->
        <div class="font-size">
            <h4>Font Size</h4>
            <div>
                <h6>Aa</h6>
            <div class="choose-size">
                <span class="font-size-1"></span>
                <span class="font-size-2"></span>
                <span class="font-size-3"></span>
                <span class="font-size-4"></span>
                <span class="font-size-5"></span>
            </div>
            <h3>Aa</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!------------ PRIMARY COLORS ------------->
        <div class="color">
            <h4>Color</h4>
            <div class="choose-color">
            <span class="color-1 active"></span>
            <span class="color-2"></span>
            <span class="color-3"></span>
            <span class="color-4"></span>
            <span class="color-5"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!---------- BACKGROUND COLORS ------------>
        <div class="background">
            <h4>Background</h4>
            <div class="choose-bg">
                <div class="bg-1 active">
                    <span></span>
                    <h5 for="bg-1">Light</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-2">
                    <span></span>
                    <h5>Dim</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-3">
                    <span></span>
                    <h5 for="bg-3">Lights Out</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Si entendí bien, quieres guardar el ID del tema que han seleccionado en el localstorage?

Comment: Si quiero que lo guarde en local storage al momento de seleccionarlo, por defecto el bg1 esta active.

Comment: Para que me puedas entender un poco  mejor he realizado el proyecto de egator, pero el no muestra como guardar los temas localmente. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiFfDjmd0jU&t=664s

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar algo en el localstorage de esta manera:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
storage.setItem('bg1', VARIABLE);
```

Donde variable sería el valor que quieres guardar, Luego cuando quieras obtener el valor puedes usar:

```
var bg1= localStorage.getItem('bg1');
```

Esto te devolverá el valor si ya antes se ha guardado algo o un null en caso de que no tenga nada si no me equivoco.

Espero te sirva saludos.

Comment: Llamar a window no hace falta en ningún momento para acceder a sus propiedades, en su lugar podría colocar simplemente localStorage.setItem() y localStorage.getItem(), no hace falta declarar una variable. Ya que ninguna de las propiedades de window tiene necesidad de especificar el mismo.

Comment: Cierto, no es obligatorio pero es más fácil para no hacer varias referencias. Saludos.